# Passing parameters to inline form in django admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have an admin class inheriting from ModelAdmin:

```
class TemplateAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (TemplateAttributeInline, CompanyAttributeInline)
    list_display = ("name", "created", "updated","departments")
    list_filter = ['companies__company']
    list_editable = ("departments",)
    search_fields = ("name", "companies__company",)
    exclude = ("companies",)
    save_as = True
```

I want to pass a parameter to `TemplateAttributeInline` which will in turn then pass the parameter to `TemplateAttributeForm`. What is the best way to do this?

**TemplateAttributeInline:**

```
class TemplateAttributeInline (admin.TabularInline):
    model = TemplateAttribute
    extra = 0
    sortable_field_name = "display"
    form = TemplateAttributeForm
```

**TemplateAttributeForm**

```
class TemplateAttributeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Template
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(TemplateAttributeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.fields['attribute'].queryset = Attribute.objects.filter(#WANT TO FILTER BY THE ID OF THE COMPANY THAT OWNS THE TEMPLATE WE ARE EDITING ON THE ADMIN PAGE)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a function that returns a class for the form:

```
def TemplateAttributeForm(param):

    class MyTemplateAttributeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Template
        def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
            super(TemplateAttributeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
            #do what ever you want with param

    return MyTemplateAttributeForm
```

Use it in another funtion to define the `TemplateAttributeInline`

```
def TemplateAttributeInline(param):

        class MyTemplateAttributeInline (admin.TabularInline):
            model = TemplateAttribute
            extra = 0
            sortable_field_name = "display"
            form = TemplateAttributeForm(param)

        return MyTemplateAttributeInline
```

To finish, use this function in your `TemplateAdmin` definition:

```
class TemplateAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (TemplateAttributeInline(param), CompanyAttributeInline)
    ....
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work for what I want it to do but works as an answer for the question asked so accepted

Answer (score 2):

To complement the response by [Sylvain Biehler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30782297/8346096), I added the following code to make the inline form dynamic. Here is the reference at [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_inline_instances). The method "get_inline_instances" is called on first time "loading", after "saving", and on "reloading". On "add" events, None is passed.

Here, "obj" is the model instance the admin form is currently bound to. It is "None" for unbound (add new) forms. Instead of directly passing the model instance "obj", you can pass any attribute of it, e.g. obj.id. In this case, you need to first check if the instance is not None.

```
class TemplateAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):
   ...
   inlines = (TemplateAttributeInline(param), CompanyAttributeInline)
   ...
   def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None): 
     return  [
         TemplateAttributeInline(obj)(self.model, self.admin_site), 
         CompanyAttributeInline(self.model, self.admin_site), 
       ]
```